# jQuery: Expand only one panel at a time

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Inside each `<li>` when `<i>` is clicked it expands and collapses the `<ul>` that follows. Need to make it so that once another `<i>` is clicked it collapses the previous `<ul>`.

See my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zb2eu19g/5/)

```
<ul class="nav-main">
    <li> <a href="/en/courses">Courses</a><i class="expand closed"></i>

        <ul class="drop">
            <li><a href="#">Campuses</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Online Learning</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Start dates and schedules</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Learning and Support</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="#">Outcomes</a><i class="expand closed"></i>

        <ul class="drop">
            <li><a href="#">Career Starter Program</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Progress to a degree</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Career Pathways</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to loop through each panel and ensure it is closed whenever an item is clicked, closing any that are not the item clicked.  Here's your fiddle updated:  https://jsfiddle.net/zb2eu19g/8/

The relevant JS code:

```
// Main Menu Slider
$('.nav-main .expand').on('click', function (e) {

    var clickedPanel = this;

    $('.nav-main .expand').each(function() {
        if (this !== clickedPanel && !$(this).hasClass('closed')) {
            $(this).addClass('closed').next('ul').slideUp(300, function () {
                $(this).removeAttr('style');
            });
        }
    });

    if ($(this).hasClass('closed')) {
        $(this).removeClass('closed').next('ul').slideDown(300);
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('closed').next('ul').slideUp(300, function () {
            $(this).removeAttr('style');
        });
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

If it was me, I'd extract out the logic to open and close items into functions to get rid of some of the duplication here, but this gives you a start.